# Как обрезать после 3ей запятой?

Tags: c#

Есть текст - `showAcabado(this, 'http:', 'BLACK', '', '')`

Нужно обрезать до `BLACK`
Как это делается?

Comment: Приведите пример того, что должно получится в итоге. P.S.: [String.Substring](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: @XelaNimed BLACK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё как вариант:

```cs
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string line = "showAcabado(this, 'http:', 'BLACK', '', '')";
        // разделяем строку по запятым
        string[] parameters = line.Split(new char[]{','});
        // удаляем у третьего элемента массива пробелы и апострофы
        // в начале и конце строки
        string thirdParam = parameters[2].Trim(new char[]{' ', '\''});
        Console.WriteLine("After processing: " + thirdParam);
    }
}
```

Кончено необходимы проверки, но в отсутствии информации о синтаксисе и возможных значениях они опущены.
"Поиграться" можно [здесь](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JkpL00).

Answer (score 2):

Можно через метод split(",") у String. Вернет тебе массив строк, нужно будет в новую строку объединить первые 2 эл-та этого массива.

Можно посимвольно пройтись и считать запятые, после определенной запятой - выйти из цикла и сохранить те символы, по которым шел

Только если в "словах" могут быть запятые и их не нужно учитывать - первый способ не подойдет. Тогда можно все равно по второму варианту, но нужна дополнительная логика проверки открытия/закрытия скобок и кавычек